# From html to mySQL: Submit button does not work

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have made an webpage and would like to enable the option to submit your email address.
i need that email address into a mySQL database. I made the html code and made the php code.
But when i press the submit button on the webpage, i'm transfert to my php code within my browser. So, i get to see the actual php code. No data is placed within mySQL database.

This is the html form

```
<form name="email" action="email.php" method="POST">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Wat is je email adres?" aria-label="Wat is je email adres?" aria-describedby="button-submit" />
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="button-submit" type="submit">Ready for take-off?</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is the php code.

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];

$connectie = new mysqli('localhost','root','','beveiliger schiphol');
if ($connectie->connect_error){
    die('Sorry, je email is niet opgeslagen. Probeer het opnieuw!' . PHP_EOL);
    echo $connectie->connect_error; 
} else { 
    $stmt = $connectie->prepare("insert into registration(email");
        values("?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    echo "Yes, gelukt! Ik heb je email adres ontvangen! Ik neem zo snel mogelijk contact met je op!";
    $stmt->close();
    $connectie->close();
}
?>
```

What should i do to make this work?

Comment: _... i get to see the actual php code..._ Have you installed php?

Comment: besides having pho uinstalled to process the code your code has an error `$stmt = $connectie->prepare("insert into registration(email) values (?)");`

Comment: Yes i do have php installed. I work with visual studie for this. What could i do to make the error disapear?

Comment: You need to put this code inside a server like Apache with php interpretation enabled. XAMPP is a good way to start. But for simple development tests you can use `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080` on comand line (cmd on Windows, or any terminal in Linux) inside application folder and access from your browser in `localhost:8080`.